# Assign edge direction based on edge parameter

Tags: bioinformatics, igraph, cytoscape

Is it possible to assign edge direction based on a edge attribute in R `igraph`?

Suppose I have a following edge table. I can either created a directed graph or an undirected graph using `graph_from_data_frame()`. But as seen here some are directed edges while others are undirected. Is it possible to create it?

```
Node1 Node2 Directional
Node2 Node3 Undirected
Node1 Node3 Directional
Node1 Node4 Undirected
Node4 Node2 Directional
```

One method could be to separate the directed and undirected edges, create a graph separately and then merge them. Any other efficient method?

Comment: Since you tagged `cytoscape` I'll point out that you can use RCy3::createNetworkFromDataFrame() to load a network like you have. Then you would use the directionality column to control whether you visualize arrowheads or not. So, the model is always directional, but the view can be customized per edge.

Answer (score 0):

When using `igraph`, I don't think you can enclose both directed and undirected edges on the same plot. However, we can use bidirectional edges as an alternative of undirected edges, and create a directed graph in turn.

Below is a possible option

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(
  rbind(
    df,
    transform(
      subset(
        df,
        V3 == "Undirected"
      ),
      V1 = V2,
      V2 = V1
    )
  )
)
```

and `plot(g)` gives

[image]

## data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = c("Node1", "Node2", "Node1", "Node1", "Node4"
), V2 = c("Node2", "Node3", "Node3", "Node4", "Node2"), V3 = c("Directional",
"Undirected", "Directional", "Undirected", "Directional")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-5L))

> df
     V1    V2          V3
1 Node1 Node2 Directional
2 Node2 Node3  Undirected
3 Node1 Node3 Directional
4 Node1 Node4  Undirected
5 Node4 Node2 Directional
```